# how do we send file from django to reactjs where i dont need RESTFRame work?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I am new to ReactJS,I am using a django as backend, React as frontend i need to send a dict/json to reactjs which is locally created by choices not from data base. is there a way to send Data from django to reactjs without restframe work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonResponse instead of ordinary HttpResponse:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def hello_dictionary(request):
    data = {'name': 'Alison', 'grade': 9}
    return JsonResponse(data)
def hello_list(request):
    data = [{'name': 'Alison', 'grade':9}, {'name': 'Alice', 'grade': 8}, {'name': 'Tom', 'grade': 10}]
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

If you pass something that is not a dictionary remember to add **safe=false**

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects